# Load Image and Fade In, but in sequential way

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to load my images and fade in. Its working. But lets suppose that I have 4 images. Right now, my script its working by loading the last image, not the first. How can I make my js load the first image, and just start loading the second after the first has been loaded?

Here's my code:

```
$(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        $("#load").load('load.html', function() {
            $('#load img').hide();
            alert($("#load img").length);

            $('#load img').each( function(){
                $(this).on('load', function () {
                    $(this).fadeIn();
                });
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: _"but in a crescent way"_ - What do you mean by that?

Comment: yes, can you expand on what you mean by 'crescent way'?

Comment: Let me know if I'm on the right track.  You're trying to preload images(in this case 4 images) one at a time.  Once the first images loads, you want it to fadeIn().  Once all that is done, you want to rinse and repeat for the rest of the images?

Comment: also, the '#' symbol is the id specifier.  From what I can infer, you have several elements with the same '#load' id.  It's against the standards to have multiple elements with the same id.  try changing '#load' to '.load' to make it a class(which allows you to have multiple elements with the same class specifier).

Comment: There is really no way to do it except to use something like the logic I have below. You need to setup a queue and anytime a load event happens test to see if the next item in the queue is ready. Then in your fadeIn callback, you test to see if the next image is ready to fadeIn. And so on. This way, you load all your images at once and animate them in a chain.

Comment: @LoganBesecker - From the code shown it looks like the OP has _one_ #load element: after loading content into that element he then goes on to manipulate that content (where the content includes multiple images not accessed via id).

Comment: Sorry, I mean sequential way. Load 1, then 2, 3 and goes on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ron's solution is a little over-engineered IMO. If your intention is indeed to load all of the images before the animation starts, then you could do something similar to the following:

```
$(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        $("#load").load('load.html', function() {
            $('#load img').hide(); // I would recommend using css to hide the image instead
            alert($("#load img").length);

            $("#load img").each(function(i, image) {
               setTimeout(function() { // For each image, set increasingly large timeout before fadeIn
                  $(this).fadeIn();
               }, 2000 * i);
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: It's simpler and will work, but I am definitely a stickler for bulletproof, fluid behavior to give users a predictable behavior that is event driven, not based on timers and guesswork.

Comment: @RonGilchrist If we were talking about an interface for visualizing important data in realtime, I would agree. But it sounds like what OP really wants are special effects. I think the tradeoff of simpler code vs exact logic is merited in this case.

Answer (score 1):

See http://jsfiddle.net/5uNGR/15/

Try something where you are not trying to perform a fadeIn on each image as they load, but test the ok-ness of the next image in your animation queue each time ANY load event happens, then on the animation callback, see if the next one is ready. Here is a script that should work.

BTW, see http://www.sajithmr.me/javascript-check-an-image-is-loaded-or-not for more on image readiness testing.

```
$(function () {
    // util fn to test if image loaded properly
    var isImgLoadOk = function (img) {
        if (!img.complete) { return false; }
        if (typeof img.naturalWidth != "undefined" && img.naturalWidth == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    };

    $("a").on('click', function () {

        $("#load").load('load.html', function () {

            var imgs = $('#load img').hide(), //create image array and hide (chaining)
                animIndex = 0, //position in the animation queue
                isFading = false; //track state of whether an animation is in prog

            // this is a load handler AND is called in the fadeIn callback if 
            // not at last image in the collection
            var fadeNextImg = function () {

                // make sure a load event didn't happen in the middle of an animation
                if (isFading) return;

                // last image in animation queue?
                var isLast = animIndex == imgs.length - 1;

                // get the raw image out of the collection and test if it is loaded happily
                var targetImage = imgs[animIndex];
                if (isImgLoadOk(targetImage)) {
                    // jQuery-up the htmlImage
                    targetImage = $(targetImage);

                    // increment the queue
                    animIndex++;

                    // set animation state - this will ignore load events
                    isFading = true;

                    // fade in the img
                    targetImage.fadeIn('slow', function () {
                        isFading = false;
                        // test to see if next image is ready to load by 
                        // recursively calling the parent fn
                        if (!isLast) fadeNextImg();
                    });

                }
            };

            imgs.on('load', fadeNextImg);

        });

        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: @ Ron Gilchrist Is there any way I can load 5 images at a time ? I am trying a workaround but to no avail in your jsfiddle.

Comment: I modernized the example and took a different approach http://jsfiddle.net/5uNGR/25/